# iOS Interapp two way communication using x-callback-url

Tags: ios, swift, x-callback-url

I have been following [this](http://x-callback-url.com/examples/) link to implement interapp two way communication using `x-callback-url`. So I made two different app - *SourceApp* & *TargetApp*.

**SourceApp**

The URL Scheme:
[image]

And implementation to open TargetApp as follows:

```
@IBAction func btnOpenAppPressed(_ sender:UIButton){

        let url = URL.init(string: "targetapp://x-callback-url/translate?x-success=sourceapp://x-callback-url/acceptTranslation&x-source=SourceApp&x-error=sourceapp://x-callback-url/translationError&word=Hello&language=Spanish")

        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)){

            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
}
```

AppDelegate method to receive the response back from TargetApp:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        print("Response From TargetApp==>\(url.absoluteString)")
        return true
}
```

**TargetApp**

The URL Scheme:
[image]

AppDelegate method to receive the request from SourceApp:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        print("Response From SourceApp==>\(url.absoluteString)")

        return true
}
```

IBAction of TargetApp to send the response back to SourceApp:

```
@IBAction func btnBackToSourceAppPressed(_ sender:UIButton){

        let url = URL.init(string: "sourceapp://x-callback-url/acceptTranslation?x-source=TargetApp&word=Hola")

        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)){

            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
}
```

Now the problem is, I can open the TargetApp from SourceApp but can't return from TargetApp to SourceApp. I even looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275330/how-to-use-x-callback-url) approach but I found it same as mine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of struggle I found that I was not using `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in plist. I also found that in Objective-C if I skip `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` I can easily communicate between those two apps. But if you are using swift you must you `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` otherwise, you will get

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "targetapp://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme targetapp"
```

So, I had to use

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>targetapp</string>
    </array>
```

in SourceApp's plist and

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>sourceapp</string>
    </array>
```

in TargetApp's plist.

I made [two demo apps](https://github.com/palash89/InterAppCommunication) that easlily demonstrates inter app two-way communication using x-callback-url.